# C# Specific type for general DependencyProperty of type object

Tags: c#, xaml, types, casting, dependency-properties

I have a problem with DependencyProperties. I have the following code:

```
public object Value
{
    get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(object),
    typeof(owner), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

protected Type ExpectedType { get; set; }
```

What it's supposed to do is that the ExpectedType property is the type that Value DependencyProperty should have. So, for example the owner class decides that it wants to receive a double, so the ExpectedType is double. Everything's fine for now because general object handles anything and the owner just needs to cast it. But generally in my owner class(es) I want to set the Value property in xaml like this (for double and for HorizontalAlignment enum respectively):

```
<OwnerClass Value="100"/>
<OwnerClass Value="Left"/>
```

The problem is that the assigned value will be a string while I would like to to have the xaml designer be able to assign a proper type based on the ExpectedType property without the cast at runtime in code behind whenever Value changes. I know I can do it like this:

```
<OwnerClass>
    <OwnerClass.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
    </OwnerClass.Value>
</OwnerClass>
```

but I'd love to know if it's possible to do it using the shorter syntax (the solution may be different than whatever I present here as long as it does the trick). I tried to find the solution on the internet but I couldn't find anything useful. If anyone knows how to do it I'd be very grateful for an answer.

Comment: All the XAML designer and compiler sees is a DependencyProperty of type `object`. Hence why the type of value it generates from the XAML element attribute for Value is always a `string`. You could use a change handler for your DP where you validate and convert any object that this DP receives. However, this in itself is problematic, since when somebody/something assigns some value object to your DP, and your DP change handler converts and thus changes the value od the DP "under the rug", all sorts of weird side effects and strange bugs could be triggered (especially if bindings are involved)

Comment: If the semantics of Value need to change case by case, then also the behavior/semantics of the owning type (OwnerClass) would probably change case by case (i guess) -- which perhaps would make it a good idea to define different owner class types which implement the different behaviors with Value DPs of different (appropriate) types...

Comment: If you need/want to keep the Value DP of type object, but with different preferred value types, you might also look into using a CoerceValueCallback with your DP for conversion of the input object to an object of the preferred data type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation)

Comment: @elgonzo I'm looking for a general solution. For example one of the owner classes I want to have is a Setter class. When I assign the property which will be set (for example HorizontalAlignment on some FrameworkElement) I extract the type and know exactly what will be set. I just don't know if it's possible to somehow modify the DependencyProperty's type or try to hint the more specific type to xaml.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, the XAML designer/compiler takes the data type of the DP into account (and there are probably attributes to provide further hints to the XAML compiler, but i can't recall; however, such attributes would also be of no help as they are - like the data type of the DP - constant and set at compile time. (In constrast, the actual content of your ExpectedType property - an individual Type object - is not set at compile time but at run-time)